# Best version of Ubuntu for my old computer?

Tags: 14.04

My computer is old.  It has a 900 Mb processor, 1.2 Gb of RAM and 500 Gb HDD.
Right now I'm running Lubuntu v12 and most of my stuff is working.

System updater wants me to update to Ubuntu V14.04.5.

Should I update ?  What is the best version my my old desktop ?

Comment: You should always run a supported release. 12.04 is no longer supported. Keep using Lubuntu which is light on resources but please upgrade to or install a supported release.

Answer (score 0):

I would personaly use Lubuntu. It is a very fast and lightweight OS. It also comes with some preinstalled apps so you ussually have everything you need.

Minimum supported requirements of Lubuntu:

```
266 MHz processor;
128 MB;
3 GB hard drive;
no fancy graphics
(I read someone installed on 128MB RAM and then removed 64MB RAM and it still worked, 
not as fluid as previously, but still working)
```

About Lubuntu:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu

Lubuntu WebPage:
http://lubuntu.net/

Other option could be Arch Linux and isntalling only the bare minimum and LXFCE desktop environment (this one is use by Lubuntu) - or if LXFCE doesnt meet you requirements you can try i3wm or openbox windows managers. Arch is the harder option.